# Faster method for copying postgresql databases

Tags: postgresql

I have 12 test databases on a test server and I generate the dump from the main server and copy it to the test server every day. I populate the test databases using:

```
zcat ${dump_address} | psql $db_name
```

It takes 45 minutes for each database. Is it faster if I do that for just one database then use:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE olddb;
```

for the rest? Are there any other methods I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how much data and indexes there is. Some ideas to speed things up include:

- Make sure the dump does not `INSERT` commands - they tend to be much slower than `COPY`.
- If you have many indexes or constraints, use the custom or archive dump format and then call `pg_restore -j $my_cpu_count`. `-j` controls how many threads are creating these concurrently, and index creation is often CPU-bound.
- Use faster disks.
- Copy `$PGDATA` in its entirety (rsync or some fancy snapshots).

Comment: Definitely use pg_dump custom format (`-Fc`) and pg_restore rather than piping through psql.